# How to use a loop to input data into arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to make a simple program where the user inputs employee information into a database for five employees; including name, age, wage, and an ID that is stored automatically. I seem to be having trouble however, getting the loop to work, and run into problems after the first array. I suspect there is a problem located within the for loop. Can anyone help me? Here is the code:

```
package database;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Justin
 */
public class employees {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] names;
        names = new String[4];
        int[] id;
        id = new int[4];
        double[] wage;
        wage = new double[4];
        int[] age;
        age = new int[4];
        System.out.println("This program is designed to store data for 5 employees.\nEnter data for 5 employees\n");

        for (int count = 0; count <= 4; count++){
            //Used to enter data for each employee
            id[count] = count;
            System.out.println("Enter the name of employee number " + id[count]);
            names[count] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the wage of " + names[count]);
            wage[count] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the age of " + names[count]);
            age[count] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("All employees are now in the database.");
        System.out.println("Enter the name or ID number of an employee to access their data");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two problem with your code:
First one is make the array declaration of 5 elements.
Second one is the use of `scan.nextLine()` change it to `scan.line()` or `scan.readLine()`. This will solve your problem.
Because What is happening is that the call to nextLine() first finishes the line where the user enters the age of first employee. Why? Because nextInt() reads only one int and does not finish the line.

So your code now look this:

In declaration

```
 String[] names;
 names = new String[5];
 int[] id;
 id = new int[5];
 double[] wage;
 wage = new double[5];
 int[] age;
 age = new int[5];
```

and while reading code change this:

```
 System.out.println("Enter the name of employee number " + id[count]);
 names[count] = scan.nextLine();
```

To:

```
 System.out.println("Enter the name of employee number " + id[count]);
 names[count] = scan.next();
```

Comment: This solved my issue in a way my novice mind can begin to grasp. However, I'm still a bit confused at the difference between "next" and "nextLine", but I can look that up. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store 5 values in each array, but your arrays were initialized to contain only 4 elements.

This, for example, creates a `String` array that can store up to 4 elements:

```
String[] names = new String[4];
```

If you need to store 5 elements you should do:

```
String[] names = new String[5];
```

You could avoid such mistakes by using a variable to specify the number of employees you want to store:

```
int numEmployees = 5;
String[] names = new String[numEmployees];
int[] id = new int[numEmployees];
double[] wage = new double[numEmployees];
int[] age = new int[numEmployees];

for (int count = 0; count < numEmployees; count++) {
    // read and store employee information
}
```

Or better yet, you could create an `Employee` class to store the data for each employee:

```
public class Employee {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final double wage;
    private final int age;

    public Employee(int id, String name, double wage, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.wage = wage;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    // Write the getters for the other fields.
}
```

And store the information in a `List<Employee>`:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int numEmployees = 5; // You could also read this from the input
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
for (int count = 0; count < numEmployees; count++) {
    int id = count;
    String name = scan.next();
    double wage = scan.nextDouble();
    int age = scan.nextInt();
    employees.add(new Employee(id, name, wage, age));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I seem to be experiencing the same issue consistently, however, where when I start to enter the data for the second array the program will say: "Enter the name of employee number 2
Enter the wage of "

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful when I try this with multiple classes

Answer (score 0):

### short answer:

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 4; count++)
```

the error is here :

```
count <= 4
```

it should be :

```
count < 4
```

### why ?

your array holds 4 values, so you want to loop only 4 times, the for loop works as follows

```
for( declaredVariables ; iterationCondition ; postIterationAction ){
    codeBlock
}
```

the loop first goes in the "declaredVariables" area once, and not more than once

then it starts like that:

```
while ( iterationCondition == true ){
    // invoke codeBlock
    // invoke postIterationAction 
}
```

once iterationCondition returns false, it stops

so your count when it is declared it is 0, and your condition is count <= 4, so your iterationCondition will return true in the following cases

```
1) count = 0
2) count = 1
3) count = 2
4) count = 3
5) count = 4
```

5 iterations, will lead to insert 5 values in your array that holds 4 elements only

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You really should create an Employee class and create an ArrayList of Employees. If you are using arrays to build business algorithms you are depriving yourself of modern programming conveniences and best practices.

Comment: Of course, just saying that there are much easier, more accessible approaches.